# How can I get temperature data for each Country (Annual)

Tags: data-request, weather

I need maximum and minimum temperature data of each countries annually.

I searched a lot but could not find the values.

Could you give links if it is possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is very coarse data from the worldbank. It shows historical average temperature per country:

http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/cckp_historical_data

Using their Climate API you can get slightly more detailed information and by per year. I believe they have data going back to 1961.

http://data.worldbank.org/developers/climate-data-api

Berkeley Earth provides aggregated data on world temperature averages going back to 1750, and country/city data going back to 1960.

http://berkeleyearth.org/data

Then there is NASA's global temperatures database collected from 500 stations, some going back to 1720. I haven't used this tool yet, so I'm not sure how to navigate it.

http://gcmd.gsfc.nasa.gov/KeywordSearch/Metadata.do?Portal=GCMD&KeywordPath=&EntryId=Rimfrost&MetadataView=Data&MetadataType=0&lbnode=mdlb3

Then there is NOAA. It's datasets, while primarily US, includes datasets for data collecting from weather stations around the world:

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access