# How can I find annual temperature data for Chile?

Tags: data-request, chile

How can I find annual average temperatures for Chile?

Not monthly but annually. And not changes to average.

Comment: What temperature are you looking for - land surface, air,...? Are you looking for measured data or model data as well?

Comment: I answered a question like this (per country) back in Feb - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-get-temperature-data-for-each-country-annual

Comment: I am looking for land temperature, just measured data. I am looking for data on Chile, the average temperatures annually. All I have been able to find so far are changes to average over time or monthly data.

Comment: You can just average the average monthly temperatures from Jan - Dec to get the average annual temperature.