# Annual Mean temperature of Africa countries for past 50 years?

Tags: data-request, africa

I'am trying to find annual mean temperature data for all countries in Africa for past 50 years.

The data should not be mean of the entire 20 years, but should be yearly mean. 
Can somebody please redirect me to a good source of data?

This is for research work.

Comment: This question looks like it would be better researched/asked at [opendata.se].

Comment: Thanks. I am new here. I will also post this question to OpenData.

Comment: [The World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/AG.LND.PRCP.MM) is usually a good source for stuff like this.  I don't think you'll get data from 50 years back, though

Comment: iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCEP-NCAR/.CDAS-1/.MONTHLY/?Set-Language=en

Comment: It's not a good idea to use 'country' as the spatial entity.

Comment: I answered a question like this back in Feb. - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-get-temperature-data-for-each-country-annual

Answer (score 2):

A good source 1961-1999 is http://gaez.fao.org/Main.html#

lots of atmospheric parameters can be found at (1979-2015): 
http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/

You can use zonal statistics with country polygons to obtain annual values per country. You can get country shapefiles at http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/