# Where I can get daily temperature data for each country?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for daily temperature data for each country for each year. I don't need data for all the years but one of the most recent year i.e. 2018 or 019.

Here is a similar question posted here but it is based on mean data rather than daily temperature data?

[How can I get temperature data for each Country (Annual)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-get-temperature-data-for-each-country-annual)

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the information provided here: [How can I get temperature data for each Country (Annual)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-get-temperature-data-for-each-country-annual)

proved to be sufficient for my purpose.